# Copy a range of cells from a closed workbook to another workbook - Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells from a closed workbook to another workbook.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\yixuanjiang\Desktop\Performance Report\Risk Test-simplified.xls"
Workbooks("Risk Test-simplified").Worksheets("Summary").Activate
Workbooks("Risk Test-simplified").Worksheets("Summary").Range("B9:F16").Copy
Workbooks("Summary-v1.0").Activate
Worksheets("Automation").Range("B155").PasteSpecial

Workbooks("Risk Test-simplified").Worksheets("Summary").Activate
Workbooks("Risk Test-simplified").Worksheets("Summary").Range("Q9:U22").Copy
Workbooks("Summary-v1.0").Activate
Worksheets("Automation").Range("H152").PasteSpecial
```

I run into error on the last line:

```
Worksheets("Automation").Range("H152").PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are after the used range of cells you can do something like this.

I think the reason it's failing is because you are not qualifying your range.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim MasterWS As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CopyRange As Variant
Dim lrowOtherSheets As Long
Dim LRow As Long

Set MasterWS = Sheets(1)
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set CopyRange = ws.UsedRange
CopyRange.Copy

LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MasterWS.Range("A" & LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```